# Basis for Clifford algebra $Cl^2 (W)$ and quotient space $Cl^3(W)/Cl^2(W)$

Tags: mathematical-physics, quantum-mechanics, clifford-algebras

Consider a basis $(c_1 ^ {\dagger}, c_2 ^ {\dagger}, c_1 ^ {\dagger}, c_1, c_2, c_3 )$ of creation and annihilation operators for $W=V \oplus V^*$.

I need help to write the basis for [Clifford algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clifford_algebra) $Cl^2 (V \oplus V^*)$=$Cl^2 (W)$. By definition, 
$$
Cl^2 (V \oplus V^*) := \bigoplus_{l =0 }^2 T^l(W)/I,
$$
where $I$ is two sided ideal generated by $(xy+yx)-b(x,y).1$ where $b$ is the canonical bilinear form attached to $W.$

I wrote 
$$
Cl^2 (V \oplus V^*) = \mathbb{C}/I \oplus W / I \oplus W \otimes W/I.
$$

Is this correct?

What is the basis for $Cl^2 (V \oplus V^*)$? Also, how can I write basis for quotient space $Cl^3(W)/Cl^2(W)$? For the latter, I am assuming that it is enough to understand the basis for $Cl^3(W)$. Then I can simply consider the coset of each basis element. Right?

Comment: Clifford algebras are only $\mathbb{Z}_2$-graded, with a $\mathbb{Z}$-filtration.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with the context of your question, but the Clifford algebra of a direct sum can easily be written using the [graded tensor product](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/202718/tensor-product-of-graded-algebras). If $W=V_1\oplus V_2$ with bilinear forms $b,b_1$ and $b_2$ respectively ($b(x,y) = b_1(x_1,y_1) + b_2(x_2,y_2)$). Then,
$$
\operatorname{Cl}(W,b) \simeq \operatorname{Cl}(V_1,b_1)\hat{\otimes}\operatorname{Cl}(V_2,b_2).
$$
With this I believe that:
$$
\operatorname{Cl}^i(W,b) \simeq \bigoplus_{j+k=i}\operatorname{Cl}^j(V_1,b_1)\hat{\otimes}\operatorname{Cl}^k(V_2,b_2).
$$

Comment: I have made my question more clear, hopefully by adding the details of the context. Please have a look at it!

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help.